# Invalid Frame error in debug mode with PyDev and Eclipse in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, terminal, pydev, debug-mode

I use Elipse and PyDev plugin and I get an error meassage `[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.` when try to enter some command in terminal in debug mode.

I'm currently using:

1. UBUNTU 22.04

   :~$ lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
   Release:    22.04
   Codename:   jammy
2. Eclipse: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
   Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
   Build id: 20230907-1323
3. PyDev Plugin: Brainwy Software Ltda | PyDev - Python Development Environment | 11.0.3.202310301107 | org.python.pydev.feature